# Selenium Exception in mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, selenium

Please tell me how to solve this exception.

[image]

```
ChromeDriver Version = 2.41
Chrome Browser version 68
Selenium stand alone version = 2.53.1
```

Where am I doing mistake in this code can you please describe me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write these line in sequence :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\chromedriver.exe"); 
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.co.uk");
```

Before launching the chrome driver , you should set the chrome driver path.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, CruisePandey, but now there is one new error, Starting ChromeDriver 2.41.57806 (some digits and alpha. are in the brackets) on port 41988, Only local connection are allowed. So what I do now. Please suggest

Comment: No that’s not an error , that’s just a notification. Was browser launched ?

Comment: No problem , Would you mind accepting this as an answer , if that worked for you? In case you want to accept it, simply click on check mark which is just under the down vote button. Or in case you want to go through accepted answer , then you can follow : (stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)